# how to write single CSV file from multiple (several thousand) netcdf files in R

Tags: r, export-to-csv, netcdf, cdo-climate

I'm trying to get a single csv file from several thousand netcdf files where each file represents a single point in time. The files contain time, latitude, longitude, and 4 different weather variables. My thought process is to merge the files into one netcdf file and then I can write a csv file from that but I'm not sure how to merge 29000 files with a simple code without having to write the name of the files over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Use netCDF operators. Either `cdo` or `nco`.

To merge your files in time with `cdo`, just:

```
cdo mergetime input_files output_file
```

and with using nco (according to https://linux.die.net/man/1/ncrcat):

```
ncrcat input_files outputfile
```

You can specify `input_files` with wildcard `*`. Basically, if your thousands of files are named like: file_000001.nc,file_000002.nc,...,file_vwxyz.nc, do:

```
cdo mergetime file_* files.nc
```

Other way is just to loop over the file names and do all your operations with r or whatever tool that you are using. Nevertheless, cdo or nco, are the right tools for your problem.

Comment: I'm using windows not linux.